# How to get notification if device's location is changed 5 or 10 meters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I'm working on a project where I need to store device's latitude and longitude. But I need to store them when the device makes a change of 5 or 10 meters in it's location. I googled for about 2 days but couldn't find anything that helped me. So I came up with [intuit/LocationManager](https://github.com/intuit/LocationManager) library. I can successfully get single location with this library. But the block inside `- subscribeToSignificantLocationChangesWithBlock:` this method **is executed only once irrespective of how many times the location of the device is changed**.

I've tested it with *real device* and with *simulator* too. On the simulator, I manually changed location like this: [simulate location image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EtTt.png)

But I'm not getting ***significant change*** updates.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
- (void)startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges
{
    __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    INTULocationManager *locMgr = [INTULocationManager sharedInstance];
    self.locationRequestID = [locMgr subscribeToSignificantLocationChangesWithBlock:^(CLLocation *currentLocation, INTULocationAccuracy achievedAccuracy, INTULocationStatus status) {
        __typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;

        _lastLocation = currentLocation;

        if (status == INTULocationStatusSuccess) {
            _significantChangeCount++;

            // A new updated location is available in currentLocation, and achievedAccuracy indicates how accurate this particular location is
            strongSelf.changedLatitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
            strongSelf.changedLongitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
            strongSelf.changedTime.text = [self getLocaleDateString:currentLocation.timestamp];
            if (_significantChangeCount > 0) {
                strongSelf.changedStatus.text = @"Significant change";
            } else {
                strongSelf.changedStatus.text = @"Monitor started";
            }
        }
        else {
            // An error occurred
            strongSelf.errorLabel.text = [strongSelf getLocationErrorDescription:status];
        }
    }];
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Or any other way to accomplish this task??

Comment: I couldn't add more than 2 links in my post, so adding as a comment: ***I've uploaded my whole test project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzxb70Gwq7HWMkVDNkp2WGVUcTg/view?usp=sharing)***. Any help??

Answer (score 0):

A movement of 5 to 10 meters does not count as a "significant" change in location:

> Apps can expect a notification as soon as the device moves 500 meters or more from its previous notification. It should not expect notifications more frequently than once every five minutes.

([source](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati))

If you need to monitor for changes on the 5-10 meter scale, you will need to use a different method.

Comment: Can you suggest me other different approaches? I'm new with this location services.